# Tweak QListView behaviour on click?

Tags: python, pyqt5, click, selection

When you have a `QListView` and you click on an item in view, the default behaviour is to cancel selection of (deselect) any existing selected item(s), and then set the item clicked to selected and also to "current item/index".

How might I change things so that clicking like this has no effect on selection, but does set the clicked item to "current item/index"?

NB experimentation shows that the view's `selectionChanged` slot is called before the view's `clicked` signal fires. One workaround could therefore be to record the deselected items (available in the `selectionChanged` slot) and apply selection again to these items on detecting that an (instant) click has been fired. But this would be clunky: is a more elegant way available?

Comment: Changing the selection based on a selection signal is not a good idea, as it usually results in unexpected behavior that's difficult to debug, due to recursion issues. The most obvious approach is to override the mousePressEvent in the appropriate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to musicamante's comment I was able to devise what I wanted:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if self.selectionModel() and event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.NoModifier:
        pos = event.pos()
        index = self.indexAt(pos)
        if index.isValid():
            self.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(index, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Current)
            return    
    super().mousePressEvent(event)
```

... allowing Ctrl-click, Shift-click, etc. to behave as normal, but tweaking the normal behaviour for unmodified click.